# Can't run maven

Tags: java, macos, maven, maven-3, macports

I've just installed maven3 on my macbook using the command

```
sudo port install maven3
```

But when I try to run the mvn command I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

How can I solve this?

I set my Java path:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
```

Comment: class path is what you need to set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to set Maven environment variable as you did for JAVA_HOME.

```
export M2_HOME = /path/to/maven-directory
```